# SQL Query a dataframe in Apachy Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a csv file and then query it using SQL syntax, but receiving the below error:

```
  AnalysisException: Table or view not found: df; line 1 pos 22;
```

How can I fix this error?

Datafrane and its content look fine, and I can use head and columns without any issue.

Code and outputs are shown below:

```
sourceFile = "dbfs:/mnt/training/dataframes/people-with-dups.txt"
%fs head dbfs:/mnt/training/dataframes/people-with-dups.txt
---------------------------------------------------
[Truncated to first 65536 bytes]
firstName:middleName:lastName:gender:birthDate:salary:ssn
Emanuel:Wallace:Panton:M:1988-03-04:101255:935-90-7627
Eloisa:Rubye:Cayouette:F:2000-06-20:204031:935-89-9009
Cathi:Svetlana:Prins:F:2012-12-22:35895:959-30-7957
---------------------------------------------------
import pyspark.sql.types
from pyspark.sql.types import *
struct1 = StructType([StructField("firstName", StringType(), True),
                  StructField("middleName", StringType(), True),
                  StructField("lastName", StringType(), True),
                  StructField("gender", StringType(), True),
                  StructField("birthDate", StringType(), True),
                  StructField("salary", StringType(), True),
                  StructField("ssn", StringType(), True)
                  ])

#df=spark.read.csv(sourceFile,header=True,inferSchema=True,sep=":")
df=spark.read.csv(sourceFile,header=True,sep=":",schema=struct1)
-------------------------------------------------
df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
firstName:string
middleName:string
lastName:string
gender:string
birthDate:string
salary:string
ssn:string
------------------------------------------
**df.head(3)**
-------------------------------------------------------------
(1) Spark Jobs
Out[46]: [Row(firstName='Emanuel', middleName='Wallace', lastName='Panton', gender='M', 
birthDate='1988-03-04', salary='101255', ssn='935-90-7627'),
Row(firstName='Eloisa', middleName='Rubye', lastName='Cayouette', gender='F', birthDate='2000- 
06-20', salary='204031', ssn='935-89-9009'),
Row(firstName='Cathi', middleName='Svetlana', lastName='Prins', gender='F', birthDate='2012- 
12-22', salary='35895', ssn='959-30-7957')]


------------------------------------------
import pyspark.sql.functions
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
dz=spark.sql("select firstName from df")

AnalysisException: Table or view not found: df; line 1 pos 22;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your dataframe before using spark.sql():

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("name")
```

[Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView)